# How I can set the cursor of writing in the left-top of Input in html

Tags: html, typescript, input, alignment

I'm using Input tag in html, I wanted the height of the input box bigger. I set it to 200px.
 my code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Enter description" 
[(ngModel)]="description" style="height:200px" >
```

[image]

It worked but, the placeholder sentence and the cursor of writing starts from the middle as the image above.
How I can set the cursor of writing in the left-top of Input in html
I tried this" vertical-align:text-top, but it didn't work!

Comment: inputs are single line. If you want multiline text use textarea elements.

Comment: Or contentEditable div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just made the input box "bigger" (actually given it more height) but it still has only one text line! If you want to have a larger text area, you should use... [textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp), you can then use the `rows` attribute to decide how big you want it to be.